# Fetch Details About Personal Workspace's Owner

Tags: powershell, powerbi

In PowerShell, using `Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Scope Organizition`, I can pull a list of workspaces organization-wise. Some workspaces returned are personal workspaces (e.g. Type = "PersonalGroup", Name = "PersonalWorkspace Ben").

Is there a way to fetch any details beyond first name about the owner of the personal workspace (e.g. last name, domain user name, etc.)?

I'm looking for some way to figure out which "Ben" (in the case of the example) owns the workspace when there can be several people with that first name in the company.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try their restmethod cmdlet? Looks like all other PowerBI cmdlets are just wrappers of their REST API. Try this:

```
Login-PowerBI
# $myworkspace = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'Groups' -Method Get | ConvertFrom-Json
$workspaces = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'admin/Groups' -Method Get | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Then browse the output object in powershell ise or vscode.

Comment: Unfortunately, the raw data provided by that REST method doesn't contain the user's username or full name.